# How can I use properties exactly as they are provided by the io.fabric8 docker-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, properties, fabric8

Maven properties filled in by io.fabric8 docker-maven-plugin seem not to be interpolated when used as is.

[The docker-maven-plugin fills in some maven properties](https://dmp.fabric8.io/#start-port-mapping) (`some.host` and `some.port`) which I try to resolve.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.15.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <images>
            <image>
                <alias>...</alias>
                <name>...</name>
                <run>
                    <ports>
                        <port>+some.host:some.port:5432</port>
                    </ports>
                    <namingStrategy>alias</namingStrategy>
                </run>
            </image>
        </images>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

They are used like this:

```
<properties>
    <docker.host>${some.host}</docker.host>
    <docker.port>${some.port}</docker.port>
</properties>
```

which leads to two empty values. They contain nothing while they should contain e.g. `127.0.0.1` and `5555`.

---

If I add some characters, suddenly the values are interpolated correctly (but of course the values are useless then)

```
<properties>
    <docker.host>${some.host}+abc</docker.host>
    <docker.port>${some.port}+123</docker.port>
</properties>
```

which leads to `127.0.0.1+abc` and `5555+123`

---

Some things I tried don't work either:

```
<properties>
    <dollar>$</dollar>
    <docker.host>${dollar}{some.host}</docker.host>
    <docker.port>${some.port}${}</docker.port>
</properties>
```

which leads to an empty value and `5555null`

Comment: Where do you use these properties ? The mapping properties and the [implicit set properties](https://dmp.fabric8.io/#docker:start) are only *after* the plugin has been started, i.e. after the `docker:start` goal has run. Could you provide an example project ?

Comment: I use these properties in the same phase as when they are set because one container needs the values from the other. So it seems logical that it wouldn't work but in the past it did work (because we first put the host and the port together) We only started wondering when this new case arose where we need those values separately. Broke our heads over it... I can't provide an example project because it uses our own images that we are not allowed to make public. But I guess any docker image would lead to the same problems.

Comment: We have a workaround by now, but it is a bit of a hack so I'm still waiting to see if someone here has any idea.

Comment: Aside from this issue in which I will look shortly (btw, could you please open an issue at https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin for this since we can that track that better over there), have you considered to use [custom networks](https://dmp.fabric8.io/#network-configuration) to connect your containers together ? That way you don't need a port mapping and can used fixed ports.

Comment: Your proposal is very good. Using the docker container as the host and its fixed internal docker ports removes the need to have the maven property. And actually it can be done by simply adding a <link> in the container that needs to use it. And I'm now thinking that my problem does not have any practical use cases that cannot be solved in a better way. So maybe an issue is not needed. If you add your suggestion as a full answer, I'll accept it. Thanks for the insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Roland Huß](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207604/roland-hu%C3%9F) noted that the problem could be avoided by using dockers fixed ports. And that should be the first choice.**

But for completion, I'll add a solution that also works:

1. Trick maven into creating an empty property (e.g., using the groovy-maven-plugin)

   ```
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
           <artifactId>groovy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.0</version>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>set empty property</id>
                   <phase>initialize</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>execute</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <source>
                               <![CDATA[
                           project.properties.setProperty('empty', '');
                           ]]>
                           </source>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
   ```
2. Use the empty property to make maven interpolate the properties exposed by the docker-maven-plugin

   ```
   <docker.host>${some.host}${empty}</docker.host>
   <docker.port>${some.port}${empty}</docker.port>
   ```